# Definition of series converging absolutely to a real number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

What does it mean by a series of real number $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely to a real number $a$?

a) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_n| = a$

b) $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_n|$ converges and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n = a$

For example, there was a theorem on Cauchy product that used the notation of series converges absolutely to a real number.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely to $a$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges absolutely to $b$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_i b_j = ab$

Comment: Notice is a sequence of numbers can jump back end forth from negative to positive.  So a series can converge even if the sum of the absolute vales do not.  Example, the harmonic series 1+1/2+1/3+1/4 diverges.  But 1-1/2+1/3-1/4 obvious can't diverge as every time it goes down or up, the next step is not large enough to get back to where it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's b). It's a shortened combination of "$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely" and "$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to $a$".

a) would be something like "the (infinite) sum of the absolute values converges to $a$" (but actually this is so rarely seen that I've come up with that *ad hoc*, rather than from a standard set phrase).